# Declare a Binary Tree which takes a Generic type of Node which contains a Generic type of key value?

Tags: java, generics, binary-tree, nodes

If I have a node class(es) that can accept a generic type for it's key value:

```
class Node<K extends Comparable<K>> implements Comparable<Node<K> {
    ...
}

class KeyValueNode<K extends Comparable<K>, V> extends Node<K> {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to declare a generic binary tree class that accepts a generic type of node, which can contain a generic type of key value? I thought it would look something like this....

```
class BinaryTree<N<K>> {
    N<K> root;
    BinaryTree<N<K>> left, right;
    ...
}
```

Apologies for any glaring misunderstandings, I'm still trying to get the hang of generics and the syntax in Java, would greatly appreciate any help or insights.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary tree structure will essentially just hold a reference to the root node. So it should have the same type parameters as its nodes:

```
class BinaryTree<K extends Comparable<K>> {

    Node<K> root;
}
```

Or for the key-value design:

```
class KeyValueBinaryTree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {

    KeyValueNode<K, V> root;
}
```

Note that it's debatable whether an enclosing tree class is necessary, since it's the nodes that are pointing to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer Paul. Is it possible though to make the node type generic? I got something like this: class BinaryTree<N extends TreeNode<K>, K extends Comparable<K>> {

That being said, it kinda fell through once I tried to specify the specific insert methods for different node types

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
class BinaryTree<N extends Node<N>> {
  Node<N> root; 
  // or even better: N root;
  BinaryTree<N> left, right;
}
```

Having `BinaryTree<Node<K>>` is *not parameterizing* the class as is [the purpose of defining a generic type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html).

Comment: Not sure why `N` would be self referencing.

Comment: What place exactly? `BinaryTree` is parameterized on some `N` that should be an instance/extension of `Node` of `N`.

Comment: Shouldn't the tree contain nodes of some `Comparable` type, rather than nodes of nodes of nodes...?

Comment: Since `Node` is `Comparable` so any `N extends Node` should also be. The original idea of self-referencing comes from the fact that author of the question indicated `BinaryTree<N<K>>` which is wrong in Java. Other than that, it's not as recursive as you interpret; there are some samples on this; e.g. [Java Enums](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1331023/248082) and another random [sample](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/01/visitor-pattern-generic-and-still-type.html). Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write a generic binary tree class

```
public class BinaryTree<N extends Node<K>, K extends Comparable> {
    N root;
    BinaryTree<N, K> left, right;
}
```

(Although I assume you would not really story the BinaryTree in a binary tree and that was just for your example to show how it could be declared)

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to have a BinaryTree contain a Node and left and right BinaryTree?