# Recursive Generic Usage

Tags: java, generics

**Edited:"** *I received a very pertinent answer from 'erickson', but there is a side problem (up-casting?) that was not explicitly covered in my original example and is not solved with his answer. I've extended the example to cover this other problem, and I've included it at the end of this post. Thanks for your help.*

I'm currently facing a problem with Java generics that is related to something that has been called the ["Curiously Recurring Generic Pattern"](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=133275). I thought I had found the solution after reading the answer from Jon Skeet to this question ["java enum definition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition). Nevertheless, I found myself with different problems when I tried to apply it in my code.

I've come up with a 'small' example where the problem I'm facing appears. I hope it will be clear enough to illustrate my questions.

**Description of the example:** I want to build a graph where node types can vary. I've defined an abstract class *Node*, which defines some basic methods, and a concrete class that implements those methods, namely *ConcreteNode*. I've also created a specialization of ConcreteNode called *City*.

In a given graph, an important requirement is that all the elements should be made of the same types or subtypes of it, i.e. a graph of ConcreteNode can have only ConcreteNodes *or* Cities.

These are the definitions of my classes:

```
abstract class Node<T extends Node<T>>
class ConcreteNode<T extends ConcreteNode<T>> extends Node<T>
class City extends ConcreteNode<City>
```

These definitions make use the 'Recurring Generic Pattern' also found in the definition of the Enum class:

```
Class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

**Questions:** I'm having problem using these classes. I don't have problems if I have to stay at the City level in the hierarchy, i.e. connecting City to City, but I'm having *huge* problems when trying to access other classes.

In the following code, my problems can be seen in the signature of the methods of GraphUtil:

1. *addNewNeighbors1a* uses the raw type Node, but at least it works.
2. *addNewNeighbors1b* uses the type Node, but it doesn't compile at all (the error is included the code).
3. *addNewNeighbors1c* uses a more complex parameter for Node, that I expected to work, but it doesn't compile (the error is included the code).
4. *addNewNeighbors3* uses complex parameters for Node, but it doesn't compile again, even though the parameters are the same for node and newNode.

In synthesis, my question is **how to upcast these generic types that are parametrized on themselves?**.

I will be really glad to get help with the best signature for the methods of GraphUtil, assuming that these methods are going to be located in a library that doesn't know anything about City or even ConcreteNode.

Thank you all.

**Here's the full code of the example**

```
package test.city;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class TestCity {
    abstract class Node<T extends Node<T>> {
    public abstract void addNeighbor(T n);
    public abstract void addNeighbors(Collection<? extends T> nodes);
    public abstract Collection<T> neighbors();
    }

    class ConcreteNode<T extends ConcreteNode<T>> extends Node<T> {
    protected Collection<T> _neighbors = new ArrayList<T>();

    @Override
    public void addNeighbor(T n) {
        _neighbors.add(n);
    }

    @Override
    public void addNeighbors(Collection<? extends T> nodes) {
        _neighbors.addAll(nodes);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<T> neighbors() {
        return _neighbors;
    }
    }

    class City extends ConcreteNode<City> {
    protected String _name;

    public City(String name) {
        _name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return _name;
    }
    }

    public TestCity() {
    City nyc = new City("NYC");
    nyc.addNeighbor(new City("Boston"));
    nyc.addNeighbor(new City("Wash"));

    GraphUtil.print("Printing cities", nyc.neighbors());

    GraphUtil.printNeighbors1(nyc);
    GraphUtil.printNeighbors2(nyc);
    GraphUtil.printNeighbors3(nyc);
    GraphUtil.printNeighbors4(nyc);
    GraphUtil.addNewNeighbors1a(nyc, new City("Miami"));
    GraphUtil.addNewNeighbors2(nyc, new City("NewOr"));
    GraphUtil.addNewNeighbors3(nyc, new City("Dallas"));
    }

    static class GraphUtil {
    static void printNeighbors1(Node<?> node) {
        print("Nodes", node.neighbors());
    }

    static void printNeighbors2(ConcreteNode<?> node) {
        print("Concrete nodes", node.neighbors());
    }

    static void printNeighbors3(Node<? extends Node<?>> node) {
        print("Nodes2", node.neighbors());
    }

    static void printNeighbors4(ConcreteNode<? extends ConcreteNode<?>> node) {
        print("Concrete nodes2", node.neighbors());
    }

    static void addNewNeighbors1a(Node node, City newNode) {
        node.addNeighbor(newNode);
        print("Add city to node", node.neighbors());
    }

    static void addNewNeighbors1b(Node<?> node, City newNode) {
        // node.addNeighbor( newNode ); <---- DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
        // The method addNeighbor(capture#8-of ?) in the type
        // TestCity.Node<capture#8-of ?>
        // is not applicable for the arguments (TestCity.City)
    }

    static void addNewNeighbors1c(Node<? extends Node<?>> node, City newNode) {
        // node.addNeighbor( newNode ); <---- DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
        // The method addNeighbor(capture#9-of ? extends TestCity.Node<?>)
        // in the type
        // TestCity.Node<capture#9-of ? extends TestCity.Node<?>> is not
        // applicable for the arguments (TestCity.City)

    }

    static void addNewNeighbors2(Node node, ConcreteNode newNode) {
        node.addNeighbor(newNode);
        print("Add concrete node to node", node.neighbors());
    }

    static void addNewNeighbors3(Node<? extends Node<?>> node,
        Node<? extends Node<?>> newNode) {
        // node.addNeighbor( newNode ); <---- DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
        // The method addNeighbor(capture#8-of ? extends TestCity.Node<?>)
        // in the type
        // TestCity.Node<capture#8-of ? extends TestCity.Node<?>> is not
        // applicable for the arguments
        // (TestCity.Node<capture#10-of ? extends TestCity.Node<?>>)
    }

    static void print(String msg, Collection<?> col) {
        System.out.println(msg + ": " + Arrays.toString(col.toArray()));
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestCity();
    }

}
```

The output of running this code is the following (no surprises at all):

```
Printing cities: [Boston, Wash]
Nodes: [Boston, Wash]
Concrete nodes: [Boston, Wash]
Nodes2: [Boston, Wash]
Concrete nodes2: [Boston, Wash]
Add city to node: [Boston, Wash, Miami]
Add concrete node to node: [Boston, Wash, Miami, NewOr]
```

**Second part of the problem**

There is a related problem that I had not included in the original example because I thought the solution was also going to apply.

I've now added the following method to GraphUtil:

```
static <T extends Node<T>> T getSomeNeighbor(T node) {
    return node.neighbors().iterator().next();
}
```

And from my main class I'm trying the following:

```
City someCity = GraphUtil.getSomeNeighbor(nyc); 
someCity.addNeighbor(new City("London")); // OK

ConcreteNode someCN1 = GraphUtil.getSomeNeighbor(nyc); 
someCN1.addNeighbor(new City("Paris")); // OK, but raw

ConcreteNode<?> someCN2 = GraphUtil.getSomeNeighbor(nyc); 
someCN2.addNeighbor(new City("Berlin")); // Does not compile

ConcreteNode<?> nc = new City("");
nc.addNeighbor(new City("Bern")); // Does not compile
```

The first case works, because I know the concrete type that is returned, and it is coherent with the type provided in the parameter.

In the second and third cases I'm assuming I don't know the type City. The second case works, but I'm using the raw type ConcreteNode.

In the third case, there is a compilation error in the second line: *"The method addNeighbor(capture#3-of ?) in the type TestCity.ConcreteNode is not applicable for the arguments (TestCity.City)."*

In the example I'm using 'new City("-")' as a parameter because I don't know how to up-cast them. In the fourth case I tried to up-cast City to ConcreteNode, but it failed. The current compiler error is the following: *"The method addNeighbor(capture#4-of ?) in the type TestCity.ConcreteNode is not applicable for the arguments (TestCity.City)"*

**Questions:**

1. How can I fix cases 2 and 3 without knowing the type City?
2. How can up-cast City to ConcreteNode (or to Node)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, the example in your updated question is too contrived to help me envision where you'd have a real problem. In all of your examples, you *do* know the type of the argument to `addNeighbor` (it's always `City`). Can you show the method that you are really trying to write---that is, one where the type of the argument isn't statically declared? You might need to show how this method would be invoked too.

Comment: almost 14 years later.... did you ever manage to solve the second part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make generic *methods* as well as generic types. Using these, the problem methods in `GraphUtils` can be fixed like this:

```
static <T extends Node<T>> void addNewNeighbors1a(T node, T newNode)
{
  node.addNeighbor(newNode);
  print("Add city to node", node.neighbors());
}

static <T extends Node<T>> void addNewNeighbors2(T node, T newNode)
{
  node.addNeighbor(newNode);
  print("Add concrete node to node", node.neighbors());
}
```

Hey, wait a second… those are the same methods!

It turns out that, since they only depend on the interface of `Node`, you only need one of them to handle any `Node` implementation.

Down the road, you might find it necessary to change the `Node` interface like this:

```
public abstract <S extends T> void addNeighbor(S n);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer: it is very clear and it solves part of my problem. Nevertheless, there is another aspect of it that is not covered with your answer. I've updated the original post to include this other side. It would be great if you could help me with it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

For part 1, I would make the method signiture

```
static <T extends Node<T>> void addNewNeighbors(Node<? super T> node, T newNode)
{
  node.addNeighbor(newNode);
}
```

That way, node does not have to specifically be the same type as newNode.

For part 2, I would do something similar.

```
ConcreteNode<? super City> nc = new City("");
nc.addNeighbor(new City("Bern"));
```

Comment: The second part is not useful because I would need to know City to write ConcreteNode<? super City>, and I'm assuming I'm not.

Answer (score 1):

To your second part, again the wildcards are a problem.  ConcreteNode could presumably be of some type which City does not extend - e.g., `ConcreteNode<Suburb>` is not extended by `City` - despite the fact that you know what it is, the compiler doesn't.

Comment: You're right .... it means that my graph could be composed by different kinds of ConcreteNodes, isn't it?
If I know that is not the case, then my only options are to use raw types, or use casting?

Comment: I wouldn't say that's the only option, but your current design has boxed you in a bit, yes.

Answer (score 0):

One, your wildcards in the static methods allow for any sort of node addition, which your compiler knows isn't allowed.  Suppose you were doing graphs of proteins (like, for example, I do) and you had a `Protein extends Node<Protein>` class with instances.  Your wildcard methods, were they to work, would allow me to add said proteins.

As for fixing the problem, try defining your add methods along these lines:

```
public <U extends T> void add(U other)
```

T is defined by the class parameter, and the method allows adding any subclass of T, as defined by the local parameter U.  That should take care of your problem in one direction, though you are restricted to only adding subclasses to superclasses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Protein graph is indeed another application of the same. 
As erickson mentioned, adding the type U to add is useful to support future types. However, my original problem was with the methods of GraphUtil, and those are solved as he suggested.
Now I've added another part of the problem to the original post.