# Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface, extends

I would like to understand the following type of syntax.

Example:

```
public interface A < T extends A < T> > {

}
```

What is the logic of this interface ?

Comment: strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563335/recursive-generic-usage

Comment: related to possible uses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959335/self-bound-generic-type-with-fluent-interface-and-inheritance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794842/generics-in-java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would be used as follows:

```
class X implements A<X> { /* ... */ }
```

In other words, you are forced to make the parameter of `A` the class `X` itself, and something like `class X implements A<Unrelated>` is forbidden.

This construction gives the interface access to `X` through the generic parameter, and the type restriction makes sure that it doesn't get abused. For instance, `T` can now be assumed to expose all methods that `A` does.

<sub>Note that this construction is *formally* somewhat similar to the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in C++ (although it is technically quite different). In both languages it allows the "base class" to reason about its ultimate derived usage.</sub>

Comment: This is a great explanation. I'm wondering though, what are some applications of this other than the `Enum` usage already suggested? A linked list maybe?