# Self bounded generics

Tags: java, generics

Is there is any actual difference between these this generic

```
public class SelfBounded <T extends SelfBounded<T>>{}
```

and this one

```
public class SelfBounded <T extends SelfBounded>{}
```

?

If yes, then how can I observe them?

Comment: `SelfBounded <T extends SelfBounded<T>>` we need to go deeper...

Comment: The second one uses a raw type, that's probably not a good idea.

Comment: There's actually an example of something similar in the standard Java API: `public class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`

Comment: This totally f**** my mind on a friday afternoon. Guess I can call it a day now. +1 for that.

Comment: I have a proof, but it is too large to fit into this comment.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of similar questions here already.
You can read the following [article](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106)

Or the following questions:

- [Java Enum definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition)
- [Why in java enum is declared as Enum<E extends Enum<E>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061759/why-in-java-enum-is-declared-as-enume-extends-enume)
- [What would be different in Java if Enum declaration didn't have the recursive part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067891/what-would-be-different-in-java-if-enum-declaration-didnt-have-the-recursive-pa)

Comment: None of those links directly addresses the difference between the standard self-bounded type `SelfBounded <T extends SelfBounded<T>>` and the non-standard `SelfBounded <T extends SelfBounded>`. In other words, is the raw typed version equivalent, or does it just look similar?

Answer (score -3):

The second one uses a raw type, which should never be used.

But actually neither of these declarations are normally useful. You should almost certainly just use

```
public class SelfBounded <T>
```