# How to interpret this Java generic type definition?

Tags: java, netty

Below is some code snippet from the `netty 4.0.24` framework. It's kind of confusing to interpret the `B` type parameter.

```
public abstract class AbstractBootstrap<B extends AbstractBootstrap<B, C>, C extends Channel> implements Cloneable
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can possibly be interpreted as one form of the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#In_other_languages).

In this case, the main purpose of the type parameter `B` is to be able to refer to the inheriting type in the abstract class. For example, the `AbstractBootstrap` class has a method

```
B channel(Class<? extends C> channelClass)
```

So the return type here is *whatever type was given as the first type argument*. Looking at the known implementations of the `AbstractBoottrap` class, one finds

```
class Bootstrap extends AbstractBootstrap<Bootstrap,Channel>
```

and

```
class ServerBootstrap extends AbstractBootstrap<ServerBootstrap,ServerChannel>
```

They receive "themself" as the first type parameter. So the `channel` method of these implementations will return "the type itself".

A possible usage scenario is shown here (with some dummy classes to make it compileable and point out the relevant part) :

```
public class BootstrapExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // On a Bootstrap, calling the 'channel' method
        // will return a Bootstrap 
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        Bootstrap resultBootstrap = 
            bootstrap.channel(null);

        // On a ServerBootstrap, calling the 'channel' method
        // will return a ServerBootstrap 
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        ServerBootstrap resultSeverBootstrap = 
            serverBootstrap.channel(null);
    }
}

abstract class AbstractBootstrap<
    B extends AbstractBootstrap<B, C>, 
    C extends Channel> implements Cloneable
{
    public B channel(Class<? extends C> channelClass)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
class Bootstrap extends AbstractBootstrap<Bootstrap,Channel> {}
class ServerBootstrap 
    extends AbstractBootstrap<ServerBootstrap,ServerChannel> {}
class Channel {}
class ServerChannel extends Channel {}
```

---

<sub>An aside: I'm always advocating for type safety, but once these type parameters are nested, you may end up with class- or method declarations that imply type bounds that can hardly be checked manually. So they should only be used when the trade off between readability and type safety is really justified.</sub>

Comment: Reading this through, it looks like I could have the class declaration `class ServerBootstrap extends AbstractBootstrap<Bootstrap,ServerChannel>`, as `Bootstrap` validly extends `AbstractBootstrap` and references itself in its own declaration. Is this correct?

Comment: @MirroredFate This would not work due to the `Channel` vs. `ServerChannel` type parameter. But in principle, it is possible to create "unintuitive" (or plainly wrong) parametrizations, like `class Dog extends Animal<Cat>` in http://stackoverflow.com/q/25365589/3182664

Answer (score 1):

I think it is basically a class that have 2 parameters, B and C. The first parameter (B) must be something that extends the class itself (or a child) and the second parameter (C) must extends Channel.

It's a little strange to think in it, but you can have a class that run with objects of it same type.

Sort answer: Its parameters are itself and a channel.

Answer (score 0):

"B" seem to represent the Subclassed AbstractBootstrap itself. It think (imho ) this is a strange declaration to make appear the subclass in generic arguments .

Please look at subclass with the subtype hierarchy in eclipse, you may find something like

```
class AnyClass extends AbstractBootstrap<AnyClass,AChannel>
```

So in this example we repeat "AnyClass" in its generic declaration