# Enum syntax explanation

Tags: java, syntax, enums

Can anyone explain this Syntax -

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

Why does this let us declare Enum as ?

```
Public enum XYZ {…}
```

Comment: See [What are generics in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815528/what-are-generics-in-java). `XYZ` kinda gets turned into `class XYZ extends Enum<XYZ>`

Comment: "Why does this let us declare Enum as ?" It doesn't. The syntax for declaring enums is defined in the language spec. `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` is a self-bounded generic type, meaning there is a type variable, E, which allows you to say that a method in an enum returns "the self type" (or accepts an instance of itself as a parameter). It's also used e.g. in Comparable.

Comment: The grammar's defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)

Comment: Thank you @AndyTurner - your response made me look for self-bounded generic type and found this nice post (for anyone else who stumbles on this post and is looking for more details) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588449/self-bounded-generics which has more details on self-bounded-generics and enums. Thank you !! 


Thank you “user”. (Not sure why I am not able to tag you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this let us declare Enum as ?

It doesn't. The syntax for declaring enums is defined in the language spec.

`Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` is a self-bounded generic type, meaning there is a type variable, E, which allows you to say that a method in an enum returns "the self type".

Looking at the Javadoc, the only method which actually uses `E` is `Class<E> getDeclaringClass()`. Having `E` allows the return value on `enum MyEnum` to be a `Class<MyEnum>`.

It's also used e.g. in Comparable, where you use it to say that the `compareTo` method should only accept a parameter "of the same type".