# Whats does SomeClass<T extends SomeClass<T>> mean?

Tags: java, generics

I just saw a class declaration in our codebase that looks like this:

```
public abstract class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass<T>> implements Cloneable {
    ...
}
```

After learning from a couple of tutorials on Java generics, now I understand stuff like `SomeClass<T extends Comparable<T>`.

However, `SomeClass<T extends SomeClass<T>>` still doesn't make sense to me. Apparently, `T` must derive from `SomeClass<T>`... but `SomeClass` has not been declared yet! What is happening here?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Usually this is used as a self-reference. This allows a superclass to declare methods that return whatever subclass ends up implementing it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588449/self-bounded-generics

Comment: @İsmailY. Wow thank you so much! That's exactly what I need, didn't found it before

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, inside the abstract class there something like this:

```
public abstract class SomeClass<T extends SomeClass<T>> implements Cloneable {
    public abstract T someMethod(); //<-- variable return type should be the implementing class itself

    public abstract int someOtherMethod(T someInstance); //<-- variable parameter type should be the implementing class itself
}
```

With such declaration, when you extend the class `SomeClass` with something concrete, let's say `SomeConcreteClass`, then you'll have:

```
public class SomeConcreteClass extends SomeClass<SomeConcreteClass> {
    @Override
    public SomeConcreteClass someMethod() {
      //implementation that returns SomeConcreteClass
    }

    @Override
    public int someOtherMethod(SomeConcreteClass instance) {
      //implementation that takes in parameter this type of class
    }
}
```

When you declare an abstract class like that, you basically ask to self-reference the child class in the parameter type.

Of course you may also use another child (it would still be inside bounds as long as it extends `SomeClass`), but it's a rare use case (I'll never seen it personally)