# Java: Explanation of unknown java syntax

Tags: java, syntax

Can someone please tell me what this is doing. Its a class that holds an extending generic of itself? what does that even mean?

```
 public abstract class AbstractStructureBuilder<T extends AbstractStructureBuilder> implements IStructureBuilder
    {

       //abstract and concrete methods in here
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why in java enum is declared as Enum<E extends Enum<E>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061759/why-in-java-enum-is-declared-as-enume-extends-enume) in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3061776/829571).

Comment: @assylias I'm asking a question of unknown syntax, I cannot draw correlation to an unknown topic.

Comment: Does the link I provided help?

Comment: I commented on your answer. Thanks again for the supporting information

Comment: @stackoverflow Not sure what you mean - I'm just pointing out the fact that a very good answer has been given on a very similar question, which you might find useful.

Comment: @assylias It appeared to me that I asked the question and you indicated it was a duplicate and voted to close the question. If that close vote wasn't yours then I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer and some rational is given here: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106

Answer (score 1):

It means the `AbstractStructureBuilder` has a type parameter that `extends AbstractStructureBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much there, but I would guess this could be a class for representing nodes in a tree or graph.  The class would have generified getters and setters.  For instance a method getChildren might return a list of T.  Then one can extend AbstractStructureBuilder to, for example, make nodes in a family tree.  If you do that, then the getter will return `List<FamilyTreeNode>`.