# What is the benefit of this design pattern?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

```
interface Base<T extends Base> {

    T method();
}
```

Against this pattern design

```
interface Base {

    Base method();
}
```

The only, I guess, with `method()` in `Base` I can get the specific type.
Are there more benefits?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061759/why-in-java-enum-is-declared-as-enume-extends-enume

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just save one cast. Here is an example:

```
class A implements Base<A> {
    ...
}


A a = ...;
A b = a.method();
```

vs

```
class A implements Base {
    ...
}


A a = ...;
A b = (A)a.method();
```

You can also build on it using T parameter all over the place. Consider accepting T as a parameter or defining a local variable of type T, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can notice is that method can be of T class or any inherited classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very clear. In the second case one can return any `subclass` of `Base2`. In the first case there is no such ambiguity.