# Apply generically enum member or method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, enums, wildcard

I have an interface `ServiceArgument` which defines a `size()` promise.

```
public interface ServiceArgument {
    public int size ();
}
```

Some of my `enum` types implement this interface

```
public enum StringCode implements ServiceArgument {
    FOO,
    BAR,
    BACON,

    public int size() {
        return values().length;
    }
}
```

Some of my class follow a `EnumService` abstract class.

```
public abstract class EnumService {
    abstract void query (Enum<? extends ServiceArgument> e);
}
```

And to wrap it up, some class extends this abstract class :

```
public class ServiceTranslation extends EnumService implements Serializable {
/**some code and ctors and transient stuff etc **/

    @Override
    void query (Enum<? extends ServiceArgument> e) {
//line that matters :
        if (e.ordinal() >= e.size()) {
            throw InvalidStringCodeAsked();
    }
}
```

My problem is, I can't use e.size() at the last line, because I wouldn't use FOO.size() in my example enumeration.
Is there a way to, either :

1) specialise what the `query` method accepts as a parameter in the concrete implementations of `EnumService`

2) get the concrete type of the Enum called in `ServiceTranslation.query(MYSTERIOUS.ENUM)`, in order to be able to call `ConcreteENUM.size()`. or even ConcreteEnum.values().length, it's the same.

3) even filter everything that is not from the right enumerated type to throw directly a `InvalidEnumeratedTypeException` through method override, but i'm not familiar with multiple overriding.

4) something I didn't think of

Edit : @shmosel in the comment is right, even if I get the wrong enumeration as argument, it will never be greater than its size. No point in comparing it to its size.

Comment: How would `e.ordinal() >= e.size()` ever be possible? Also, I don't see why you need each constant to return the enum size, when you could get it from `e.getClass().getEnumConstants().length`.

Comment: In case someone gives the wrong enumerated type as argument :/ And thank you, that's a part of what I need.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "wrong enumerated type". You're comparing whichever type was passed in against *its own* enum size. It'll never fail.

Comment: If your intent is to restrict implementations of `EnumService` to a specific enum, you'll need to parameterize the class with that type (and possibly pass in the class object for more info). For example: `abstract class EnumService<T extends Enum<T> & ServiceArgument> { abstract void query(T arg); } }`

Comment: I can't understand that easily, have you any documentation on the subject ?

Comment: Not really. But you can try playing with my example to get an idea. The subclass would look like this: `class ServiceTranslation extends EnumService<StringCode> { void query(StringCode arg) { ... } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?

```
public abstract class EnumService {
    abstract <T extends Enum<T> & ServiceArgument> void query (T e);
}

public class ServiceTranslation extends EnumService implements Serializable {
    @Override
    <T extends Enum<T> & ServiceArgument> void query (T e) {
       if (e.ordinal() >= e.size()) {
            throw InvalidStringCodeAsked();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I get it right, it says query takes a T param, with T extends Enum<T> and ServiceArguments ? But why Enum<T> ?

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume - See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3061759/823393) for some discussion of that.