# Generics in Java with and abstract class

Tags: java, android, generics

I was reading some code for learn something about manage data in Android.
When i read a litle of the code...

I find this declaration.

```
public abstract class DBObject<T extends DBObject<?>> implements Cloneable{}
```

I understadn that this is and Abstract class with T that is a Generic Object
but i don't understand why y have to put a wildcart after Extend the same class.

Here is all the code
https://github.com/tasks/tasks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/todoroo/andlib/sql/DBObject.java

Comment: Please fix the code in your question and make it as a code block.

Comment: Well since the author of the code did not provide any Javadocs... why not ask him/her?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is used so that it can be parameterised with its subclasses. It would be used like so:

```
class Foo extends DBObject<Foo> { ... }
```

It appears this is done solely so that the `as()` method will return the correct type.

The reason for the wildcard is because without it you would have to somehow specify a recursive generic definition, `DBObject<T extends DBObject<T extends DBObject<...>>>` - which is impossible.

**Edit:** Although see comments below; the wildcard is not actually necessary.

Comment: I don't think you'd have to. Enum is declared in a similar way and doesn't have to be recursive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061759/why-in-java-enum-is-declared-as-enume-extends-enume

Comment: @MarcinKoziński Yes, you're right - you don't even need the `<?>` wildcard. Some IDEs may complain without it, and that might be why it is in the code sample.