# Enum implements Comparable<E> why not Comparable<Enum<E>>

Tags: java, generics

Usually, when a class implements `Comparable`, the type variable `T` is the class name, for example, `String` implements `Comparable<String>`, `Long` implements `Comparable<Long>`, `Date` implements `Comparable<Date>`，then why `Enum` implements `Comparable<E>` not `Comparable<Enum<E>>` ?

Comment: I suspect this is fallout from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061759/why-in-java-enum-is-declared-as-enume-extends-enume.

Answer (score 2):

`E` is an `Enum<E>` already.

The reason it cannot be `Enum<E>` as that implies any `Enum<E>` is comparable which only `E` is acceptable.

Comment: Sir, can you be more specific in the cannot be `Enum<E?` part ?

Comment: @user2018791 Enum <E> is not as restrictive as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `enum` class is defined as

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> ...
```

So the `E` is already an `Enum<E>`, and having it implement `Comparable<E>` already implicitly has the `Enum` part inside it.

You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition) for further information on why it's declared in this recursive fashion (because it does rather hurt the brain).

Comment: what could be wrong if `Enum` implements `Comparable<Enum<E>>` ?