# Sonar compliant way to map Enum to Name

Tags: java, sonarqube, option-type

I have the below method to map various enums in my project to their name but sonar is complaining `Code smell·Provide the parametrized type for this generic.`

```
public static String mapToName(Enum customEnum) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(customEnum).map(Enum::name).orElse("");
    }
```

Its impossible to create separate `mapToName` method for tens of enums in my project, how do I make the above method sonar compliant?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please do not use `Optional` as replacement for if-else statements. They were not intended for that purpose. Optional was intended to convey the possibility of null-values in public interfaces in code, instead of just documentation, and only that. Even using optional in a private method is against it's intention (you're supposed to know what your own code does).

Please read this answer from one of the architects behind the Optional class: [Should Java 8 getters return optional type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555)

As an excercise, you should go through the source code for Optional and count how many throwaway objects you create for *each* name mapping operation.

As for your problem, this is the correct way to solve the immediate Sonar complaint:

```
public static String mapToName(Enum<?> customEnum) {
    return customEnum == null ? "" : customEnum.name();
}
```

The question mark is a [wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) which denotes an unknown type.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> String mapToName(Enum<T> customEnum) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(customEnum).map(Enum::name).orElse("");
}
```

If you are pondering about the strange `T extends Enum<T>`:
[Why in java enum is declared as Enum<E extends Enum<E>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061759/why-in-java-enum-is-declared-as-enume-extends-enume)

Comment: I am not sure I understand, how do you suggest to implement the function?

Comment: You have a point , you don't need it. I guess it just clutters the code.