# Inheritance: Incompatible Generic Types with Same Bound

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

So, I have this `public interface NodeLevel<E extends NodeLevelEnum>`, which has methods `public E getParent()` and `public E getEnum()`. An implementing `abstract public class NodeLevelAbstract<E extends NodeLevelEnum> implements NodeLevel<E>` delegates to instances of class `A` that implements `public interface NodeLevelEnum<E extends NodeLevelEnum>`. The last declaration should mean that instances of classes that implement `NodeLevelEnum` can do something with instances of classes that implement `NodeLevelEnum`.

Now, this is `NodeLevelAbstract#getParent()`:

```
@Override
public E getParent() {
    return this.getEnum().getParent();
}
```

Results in a compiler error (I use NetBeans 7.2, btw):

```
incompatible types
required: E
found:    NodeLevelEnum
where E is a type-variable:
E extends NodeLevelEnum declared in class NodeLevelAbstract
```

To me, this means that a descendant of `NodeLevelEnum` is required, but `NodeLevelEnum` is found, which, given that the bound in Java Generics includes itself, sounds like absolute bollocks.

Why are these types incompatible? And is there any graceful way to do what I mean to do?
Thanks in advance. =)

**Update 1**

Btw, `NodeLevelEnum#getParent()` returns `<E extends NodeLevelEnum>`, and not `NodeLevelEnum`, which the error says it does.

**Update 2**

```
abstract public class NodeLevelAbstract<E extends NodeLevelEnum> implements
        NodeLevel<E> {

    protected E _enum;

    @Override
    public E getEnum() {
        return this._enum;
    }

    @Override
    public E getParent() {
        return this.getEnum().getParent();
    }

    public static <E extends NodeLevelEnum<E>> E[] getEnumLineage(E _enum) {
        ArrayList<E> ancestors = new ArrayList<>();
        E currentEnum = _enum;
        do {
            ancestors.add(currentEnum);
            currentEnum = currentEnum.getParent();
        } while (currentEnum != null);
        return (E[]) ancestors.toArray();
    }

    public static <E extends NodeLevelEnum<E>> HashMap<String, String>
        getEnumLineageValueMap(
            E _enum) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (E e : getEnumLineage(_enum)) {
            map.put(e.getCode(), e.getValue());
        }
        return map;
    }
}

public interface NodeLevel<E extends NodeLevelEnum> {

    public E getEnum();

    public E getParent();
}

public interface NodeLevelEnum<E extends NodeLevelEnum> {

    public E getParent();
}

public interface FilestructureLevel<E extends NodeLevelEnum<E>> extends
        NodeLevel<E> {

    public String getPathPrefix();
}

public class FileLevel<E extends NodeLevelEnum<E>> extends NodeLevelAbstract<E>
        implements FilestructureLevel<E> {

    protected String _pathPrefix;

    @Override
    public String getPathPrefix() {
        return this._pathPrefix;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getValueMap(Boolean withPath) {
        return getEnumLineageValueMap(this.getEnum(), withPath);
    }

    public static <E extends NodeLevelEnum<E>> HashMap<String, String>
        getEnumLineageValueMap(
            E _enum) {
        return getEnumLineageValueMap(_enum, false);
    }

    public static <E extends NodeLevelEnum<E>> HashMap<String, String>
        getEnumLineageValueMap(
            E _enum, Boolean withPath) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        FileLevelEnum[] lineage = (FileLevelEnum[]) getEnumLineage(_enum);
        for (FileLevelEnum e : lineage) {
            String value = !withPath ? e.getValue() : e.getPathPrefix()
                + e.getValue();
            map.put(e.getCode(), value);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: So have you tried changing `NodeLevel<E extends NodeLevelEnum>` to `NodeLevel<E extends NodeLevelEnum<E>>`?

Comment: Your question would be a little easier to read if you just posted a (minimal) version of your interface and class, rather than trying to describe them in prose!

Comment: Your first comment worked. Could you explain please..?

Comment: @XedinUnknown - See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/211143/823393) question.

Comment: @XedinUnknown - and [this](http://madbean.com/2004/mb2004-3/) is especially good.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, so from the awesome link #1 that you gave, I can conclude that _the type argument for `NodeLevelAbstract` has to derive from a `NodeLevelEnum` which itself has the same type argument_. I think it is going to take some time for me to fully understand this sentence, but my subconscious mind tells me it makes sense. Thank you =)

Comment: @XedinUnknown - or, perhaps more simply *an `enum` is an `Enum` of itself*.

Comment: BTW, I only had to create this wrapper because I stumbled upon a similar article before, from which I found out that Enums cannot extend, only implement. This is sad, and has lead me to tear lots of hair from my behind.

Comment: So, I am stuck again. I need to narrow the generic type in `FileLevel` so that the type is `<E extends FileLevelEnum<E>>`, and the same for the 2 static functions, because I need them to accept this type. I already understand that they cannot override the static methods in `NodeLevelAbstract`, only overload. I understand that this new narrowed-down generic type should be the type parameter for  `FileLevel`, or, even better, for `FilestructureLevel`, but when I change it to `<E extends FileLevelEnum<E>>`, it, obviously, breaks the inheritance.

Comment: Add your new question to your question instead of a comment. Provide the definition of FileLevelEnum. Try not to introduce a horizontal scroll bar. Stop using arrays with generics code. Also : https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java+programming+to+the+interface. Get rid of `HashMap` parameters/return types - use `Map`'