# Java generics extension

Tags: java, generics

I was looking at a diff and saw this code:

```
public interface Vector<T extends Vector>
```

which was replaced by this code:

```
public interface Vector<T extends Vector<T>>
```

I have trouble wrapping my head around it, what is the difference? How do they work differently?

Comment: I think this page should answer all of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Actually it does answer my question, I sometimes have trouble parsing the language of java generics parameterization in the wild.  Knowing that it is a raw type helps me think of it in terms of ArrayList vs ArrayList<String>, etc.

Comment: Very interesting recursive generic.

Comment: This is the actual explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition

Comment: Both of them do not make much sense and whoever wrote it doesn't realize that it can be done much simpler with just `public interface Vector<T>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The difference between these two declarations is that the first one produces compiler warning and the second one doesn't. This is because generic types should always be used with parameters.

This declaration ensures that if X implements Vector it must be Vector of X :

```
class X implements Vector<X> {
...
```

Anything else will produce a compiler error.

Actually such construct is used in JDK:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> implements Comparable<E>, Serializable {
...
```

it means that when we declare enum X it (implicitly) extends `Enum<X>`

Comment: "This declaration ensures that if X implements Vector it must be Vector of X" No it doesn't. Now we can make `class Y implements Vector<X>`

Comment: class Y implements Vector<X> gives compile error

Comment: No it doesn't, given class `X` as you've defined it above. Have you even tried it?

Comment: Bound mismatch: The type X is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Vector> of the type 
 Vector<T>

Comment: C'mon. I don't know what problem you are having, but you are doing something wrong. This is guaranteed to compile: interface Vector<T extends Vector<T>> {} class X implements Vector<X> {} class Y implements Vector<X> {}