# How to make type safety with generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have the class

```
public class ReportItem<ReportType extends Report>{ }
```

and the class

```
public abstract class Report implements Iterable<ReportItem>{

    private List<ReportItem<? extends Report> > itemList;

    public void add(ReportItem<? extends Report> item){
        itemList.add(item);
    }

    //Some other staff

}

public class ConcreteReport extends Report{ 
    //Some staff
}
```

The thing is the method `add(ReportItem<? extends Report>)` is unsafe in the way I could provide items aren't tied with the current report, but tied with some another and the compiler won't complain.

Is it possible to write the method `add` in a type-safe way, i.e. we could pass as an argument only that `ReportItem<T>` where T is the type of a current report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following.

```
public abstract class Report<T extends Report<T>> implements Iterable<ReportItem<T>>{

    private List<ReportItem<T>> itemList;

    public void add(ReportItem<T> item){
        itemList.add(item);
    }

    //Some other stuff

}

public class ConcreteReport extends Report<ConcreteReport> { 
    //Some stuff
}
```

The way it works is that:

- You want to parametrize `ReportItem<T>` with something that extends from `Report`
- You want to make sure that the list of `ReportItem<T>` all belong to the same type of `Report`

In order to bind the `T` parameter of `ReportItem<T>` to something that extends from `Report`, you need to parametrize the `Report` itself:

```
public abstract class Report<T> implements Iterable<ReportItem<T>>
```

you add the bind that it needs to extend from Report

```
public abstract class Report<T extends Report> implements Iterable<ReportItem<T>>
```

But you are specifying the bound for the **raw type of report**, which doesn't work, so you need to provide `Report` with the type parameter that the report receives, which is `T`.

```
public abstract class Report<T extends Report<T>> implements Iterable<ReportItem<T>>
```

This way you can parametrize the `List<ReportItem<T>>` with the concrete type that you extend with:

```
public class ConcreteReport extends Report<ConcreteReport> {
```

This way the list will be

```
public List<ReportItem<ConcreteReport>> itemlist;
```

Which is what you wanted.

And it works! :) I just hope my explanation of it makes sense.

Comment: ReportType is a Type parameter

Comment: Okay, check now. I think this should be what you want.

Comment: Wokrs perfect now. But the declaration `Report<T extends Report<T>>` looks a little sophisticated. Couldn't you give a little explanation?

Comment: Sure can, although if it works, don't forget to tick the tick on the top left :D I'll edit it into the post.

Comment: Tahnk for the explanation. Got that.

Comment: @newacct It says for me for `public abstract class Report<T> implements Iterable<ReportItem<T>>{` that "type parameter `T` is not in bound, should extend `Report`", you should try it in an IDE

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Oh I forgot, it's needed when you have two types.

Comment: @newacct yeah, it's because the `ReportItem<T>` needs `T` to be bound to `Report`