# How to allow a more precise return type in this use of generics?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to model something like a "dynamic [Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition)" in Java. There is a generic inteface `Domain` which represents a set of allowable values, and an interface `Point` that represents a particular value. Like this:

```
public interface Domain<D extends Domain<D>> {

    Set<Point<D>> points();

}

public interface Point<D> { // D works a bit like a phantom type

    public D type();

}
```

My intention is to statically forbid accidental mixing of `Point`s from different `Domain` types.

I have the following `Domain` implementation:

```
public final class Symbols implements Domain<Symbols> {

    final Set<Point<Symbols>> symbols = new HashSet<>(); 

    public Symbols(final Set<String> values) {
        super();
        for (String value : values) {
            this.symbols.add(new SymbolPoint(value));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Point<Symbols>> points() {
        return symbols;
    }

    public class SymbolPoint implements Point<Symbols> {

        private final String symbol;

        ...
    }
}
```

It seems to work OK, but now I've hit a roadblock. I want the `points()` method of `Symbols` to return the type `Set<SymbolPoint>`. Which of course doesn't work because `Set<SymbolPoint>` is not a subtype of `Set<Point<Symbols>>`. How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface `Domain` should accept a wildcard for its `points` method.

```
interface Domain<D extends Domain<D>> {

    Set<? extends Point<D>> points();

}
```

You can now change `Set<Point<Symbols>>` to `Set<SymbolPoint>` in `Symbols#points`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I think another solution would be to add a type parameter to `Domain`, like `Domain<D extends Domain<D,T>, T extends Point<D>>` but that would complicate the types a whole lot.