# Java: generic parameter extends from itself

Tags: java, generics

Sometimes, exploring java libraries I see code like this:

```
interface IIfc<C extends IIfc<C>> {}
```

Which is the purpose of take a generic that inheriths from itself?

Comment: It creates a sort of list of IIfc implementations.

Comment: Another dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/211143/18157

Comment: Yeah that's a lot better one.