# How can i make an interface in java with a function that accepts a parameter of the type that extends the interface?

Tags: java, interface

How can i make an interface in java with a function that accepts a parameter of the type that extends the interface?

For example take the interface ISelfComparable

if class A extends it then i would expect it to implement

```
bool compareTo(A other)
```

but if class B extends it then i would expect it to implement

```
bool compareTo(B other)
```

I know i can use a generic interface but it seems incorrect because it doesn't make any sense for A to extend ISelfComparable<B>

If this is impossible, what is the best practice in this kind of situation?

Comment: This will still allow A to extend ISelfComparable<B> if B is also self comparable, or i didn't understand you.

Comment: "I know i can use a generic interface but it seems incorrect because it doesn't make any sense for A to extend ISelfComparable<B>" .... what? A would be `class A implements ISelfComparable<A>` and B would be `class B implements ISelfComparable<B>` ... where do you get that A passes B? Or do you want to prevent A to ever pass B? Then you should say that.

Comment: because theoretically A could extend ISelfComparable<B>

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no solid solution for this situation, thus it would need runtime checks to be completely sure.

Comment: You can for example try `System.out.println("this: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " --> other: " + other.getClass().getSimpleName());` in your `foo` method to see how you could go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution is self-bounded generics, as seen in the `Enum` class.

```
interface Example<T extends Example<T>> {
    void foo(T t);
}

public class ExampleImpl implements Example<ExampleImpl> {
    @Override
    public void foo(ExampleImpl example) {
    }
}
```

How it works is a bit dizzying, but is explained very well [here](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=136394) for example. There is also a very good answer on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/211161/574479).

Note that it isn't foolproof, as it allows this:

```
public class ExampleImpl2 extends Example<ExampleImpl {
    @Override
    public void foo(ExampleImpl example) {

    }
}
```

But in practice the self-bounded idiom is used to express exactly the sort of thing you're after.

If you really, really, really need the parameter object to always be the exact same class as `this`, you have to do a runtime check. (It also raises the question of why you need this, but that would take us way off topic.)

Comment: Mhh, doesn't seem to solve OPs issue. When I create `class ExampleImpl2 implements Example<ExampleImpl2>`, then I can change `ExampleImpl` to `class ExampleImpl implements Example<ExampleImpl2>` and that's that OP likes to prevent.

Comment: @Tom Indeed it doesn't. AFAIK there is no way to express that exact requirement in the Java type system, this is the closest you can get.

Comment: That's what I assume also. OP would need to check the runtime type of the passed `example` object if it exactly matches `this` to be completely sure.

Comment: The canonical SO thread on this topic is probably [Java Enum definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211143/1371329).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the class `java.lang.Comparable`: it has an argument with the type of the objects that can be used int `compareTo`.

By analogy:

```
public interface ISelfComparable<T extends ISelfComparable<T>> {
    boolean compareTo(T other);
}
```

Comment: `Comparable` doesn't has the restriction OP likes to apply. Also see the other answer, it shows that your self-bounded generic doesn't fulfill that requirement either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check the type of parameter but only in runtime. For example you can implement type checking in default method:

```
interface ISelfComparable {
    default boolean compareTo(ISelfComparable param) {
        if (this.getClass() != param.getClass()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Then each implementation of this interface should look like this:

```
class A implements ISelfComparable {
    @Override
    public  boolean compareTo(ISelfComparable param) {
        ISelfComparable.super.compareTo(param);
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case if you call `new A().compareTo(new B());` then `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown