# Generic class E with type parameter to be a subclass of E

Tags: java, generics

I am relatively new to the concept of generics in Java and I cannot tell the difference between the 2 answers.

The question at hand is :
Suppose we have a generic class E and we want the type parameter to `E` to be a subClass of `E`. In other words, we allow `E<F>` only if class `F` is either `E` or inherits from `E`.

I have narrowed down the options to what is possible.

```
1. class E<T extends E>
2. class E<T extends E<T>>.
```

I believe that option 1 meet the specification for the question.
However i am confused about option 2, what does it actually extend.

Comment: You are attempting to parameterise a parent with knowledge of what its children are. This is abuse/misuse of inheritance. The parent should not care what its children are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, option 1 actually uses a raw type.

You define `E` to have a parameter `T`, so `E` is a parameterized type. If you define `T` to extend `E`, you must also specify the type parameter of `E`, or else `E` is a raw type.

So the only "valid"<sup>1</sup> option is option 2:

```
class E<T extends E<T>>
```

The `Enum` class is a well-known example of a recursive type parameter. See [Java Enum definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition).

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, the first option is also valid in the sense of syntactically correct. But raw types are only there for backward compabibility. New code should **never** contain raw types. See also [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).