# Is it possible for Java interface with generics to enforce the generic type?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Consider this example

```
    public interface Equatable<T> {
        public boolean equal(T t1, T t2);
    }

    public class Square implements Equatable<Square> {
        public boolean equal(Square t1, Square t2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is it possible for the interface Equatable to enforce Square to implement an equal function that takes in two Squares, and not just two of any types (two Strings etc)?

Comment: But what purpose do you have for enforcing this? If someone implements a `class Circle implements Equatable<Square>` in a safe way, why is that a problem? If you have a generic class or method that relies on its type variable `T` implementing `Equatable<T>`, then that class or method can have the bound `<T extends Equatable<T>>`. There is no need to restrict `Equatable` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you didn't define what is "T" in your interface, you can limit it only to classes which implements Equatable, so ***String*** will not be allowed:

```
public interface Equatable<T extends Equatable<T>>
{ 
     //...
}
```

**Works Good:**

```
public class Square implements Equatable<Square>
{
    public boolean equal(Square t1, Square t2)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

***Compilation Error:***

```
public class Circle implements Equatable<String>
{
    public boolean equal(String t1, String t2)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note**
Pay attention, it's your responsibility to put in the brackets the same Type name, because below case will not be covered by compiler.
I guess you want to disallow to use ***equal*** method for different type.

```
public class Square implements Equatable<Circle>
{
    public boolean equal(Circle t1, Circle t2)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t follow. What’s the difference between Square and Circle

Comment: @erotsppa, in Square i used <Square>, but in Circle i used <String> parameter (which is not allowed, because 'String' doesn't extends Equatable interface)

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce this to an extent with a recursive generic type.

```
public interface Equatable<T extends Equatable<T>> {
    public boolean equal(T t1, T t2);
}
```

related: [Java Enum definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition)

Comment: This does not enforce what the OP wants. With this declaration, you can have `class Square implements Equatable<Square>` and `class Circle implements Equatable<Square>`, and it would compile. The only case in which a bound like this would be useful is if you can get a `T` from a method of the interface somehow, in which case you can guarantee that the returned `T` is an `Equatable<T>`. Since in this case, the methods do not return anything with `T`, and only take in `T`, I assert that there is no code for which your declaration will compile while `interface Equatable<T>` will not compile.

Comment: The recursive type forces T to at least extend `Equatable` so it prevents e.g. `class Square implements Equatable<String>` from compiling, which is the specific example given by the OP. That is what I meant by, "_enforce this to an extent_".