# Interface type parameter extends the interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface, type-bounds

I came by this construction when reading a codebase and I can't figure out what it does/represents:

```java
public interface MyInterface<T extends MyInterface<T>> {}
```

I don't understand what the type bound does here - it seems almost recursive? What's really the restriction on `T` in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Enum definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that any class that implements the interface must specify `T` as themselves:

```java
class MyClass implements MyInterface<MyClass> {}
//       │                              ↑
//       └──────────────────────────────┘
```

Here `T` is `MyClass`, which extends `MyInterface<MyClass>`, so the `T extends MyInterface<T>` bound is satisfied.

Comment: So basically any method that takes/gives T is actually taking/giving "this class"? For example:

T someMethod(...) actually says "This method takes some parameters and gives some instance of the implementing class?

I guess that is stronger than simply saying 

```interface MyInterface {
   MyInterface foo(...)
}
```

as that could be any implementation of MyInterface

Comment: @NimrodSadeh No, you are not *guaranteed* that `T` is the type of the `this` object. E.g. `class Foo implements MyInterface<Foo> {}` and `class Bar implements MyInterface<Foo> {}` is valid, even though the `T` of `Bar` is not a type `Bar`.